# parameters sql query inside of a stored procedure mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I'm working with stored procedures in mysql, so I have the following procedure:

```sql
DELIMITER @@
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS generarEstadisticoRD @@
CREATE PROCEDURE generarEstadisticoRD ( mesInicial INT,anualInicial INT, mesFinal INT,anualFinal INT, codigoEntidad CHAR(3),mes INT )

BEGIN
    DECLARE controlador INT;
    DECLARE tipoDocumento CHAR(2);

    DECLARE cursorDocumentos CURSOR FOR SELECT DISTINCT e.claseDocIdentidadFallecido 
            FROM EstadisticoRD e  WHERE e.anual>=anualInicial AND e.anual<=anualFinal  
            AND  e.mes >=mesInicial AND e.mes<=mesFinal AND e.codOficina=codigoEntidad;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET controlador = 1;

    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS estadistico;
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 
    estadistico( TIPO CHAR(2), MES INT );

    OPEN cursorDocumentos;

    cursorLoop : LOOP
        FETCH cursorDocumentos INTO tipoDocumento;
        IF( controlador=1 ) THEN
            LEAVE cursorLoop;
        END IF 

        /**
          *Lógica
          */
        INSERT INTO estadistico(`TIPO`,`MES`) 
            SELECT DISTINCT 
                c.descripcion, 
                IFNULL( (SELECT e.numRegistrosReportados FROM estadisticoRD e WHERE e.codOficina=codigoEntidad
                    AND e.claseDocIdentidadFallecido=tipoDocumento AND e.mes=mes ), 0)
            FROM estadisticoRD e, claseDoc c WHERE e.codOficina=codigoEntidad AND e.claseDocIdentidadFallecido=tipoDocumento
            AND c.claseDoc = e.claseDocIdentidadFallecido;

    END LOOP cursorLoop;
    CLOSE cursorDocumentos;
    SELECT * FROM estadistico;
END @@ 
DELIMITER ;
```

I get the following messages when I try to execute the procedure:

```
Executed successfully in 0,001 s, 0 rows affected.
Line 2, column 1

Error code 1064, SQL state 42000: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO estadistico(`TIPO`,`MES`) 
        SELECT DISTINCT c.descripcion, 
 ' at line 24
Line 3, column 1
```

So, what  am I doing  wrong?.

**UPDATE 1:**

The I corrected the mistake with semicolon thanks @Daniel Victoria

But now I get the following mistake:

```
Error code 1267, SQL state HY000: Illegal mix of collations (latin1_spanish_ci,IMPLICIT) and (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '='
```

Exactly I get this  mistake when I do

```
SELECT DISTINCT e.claseDocIdentidadFallecido 
            FROM EstadisticoRD e  WHERE ...  AND e.codOficina=codigoEntidad;
```

why when I do `e.codOficina=codigoEntidad`  I get this mistake, how to fixed it?.

**UPDATE 2:**

To solve it, I  need to put `COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci` after to  the column that  has the mistake.

In this case the new query is :

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT * 
            FROM estadisticoRD e  WHERE e.anual>=anualInicial AND e.anual<=anualFinal  
            AND  e.mes >=mesInicial AND e.mes<=mesFinal AND e.codOficina  = codigoEntidad COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci;
```

I hope to finish this procedure the best way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are missing a semicolon (;) after the "END IF"

Comment: Vitoria, now I  have the following error when I try to call the procedure `Error code 1267, SQL state HY000: Illegal mix of collations (latin1_spanish_ci,IMPLICIT) and (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '='` What can it be?